# How to relatively size SVG fonts based upon a bounding box and specific word

Tags: java, svg, batik

I need to draw some text inside a rectangle, using SVG. I have icons defined by paths, and I have arbitrarily chosen text canvas areas for each icon, based upon the shape of the icon. What I need to do is to draw some text (which can change with each request), such that the text is centred (horizontally and vertically) within my text-canvas area, and resize the font used so that it will fit perfectly inside the canvas.

What I've been doing up to now is to generate the raw image using Batik and then using java.awt to draw the text on top of it. This has been done by starting with a font-height of 80% of the canvas area and then checking the width of the rendered font (using font metrics) and - if it's greater than the width of the canvas area - reducing it by 5% at a time until it fits. If it fits first time then no looping is involved, so it's still relatively efficient (at least for the foreseeable future).

This approach falls down on several areas though, most significantly when dealing with adding a stroke to the icon, as the bounding box of the icon changes unpredictably as the stroke increases, and so I was hoping to draw the font within the SVG itself.

Can I use a similar approach to resize the font until it fits, in SVG/Batik? How would I do this? Can someone point me to a good resource for this? I haven't found a suitable answer on Google/Stackoverflow but if I've missed an obvious one, please do send me there instead.

Many thanks in advance.